# UITableView: "didDeselectCell" method not called, although cell gets deselected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gesture, delete-row

I use UITableView with enabled "swipe to delete" animation.

I need to monitor `didDeselectCell` method to enable/disable some controls on the app.

However, if the user initiates "swipe to delete" gesture, opens the "delete" button and then reverses the gesture (without completion), the cell gets deselected and no event is being registered.

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to enable `didDeselectCell` event to be triggered in this case as well?
2. How is it possible to get notified, that the cell got automatically deselected via "swipe to delete" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didDeselectRowAt` (and `willDeselectRowAt`) are only called if the user taps to select a row while another row is already selected.

**NOT called** when editing begins, or when deselecting / selecting via code with `.deselectRow(at: ...` or `.selectRow(at: ...` etc.

One option would be to implement `willBeginEditingRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let iPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        print("the row at \(iPath) was selected...")
        // do stuff for that row
    }
}
```

Depending on what all you need to do, this may or may not work for your case.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. Although, when this method is called, the tableview still has a row selected (which will be deselected after this method ends). Unfortunately, there are no method with signature that is called after editing begins, i.e. `didBeginEditing`, but still the method you've suggested works for my case too.

Comment: @RichardTopchiy - yeah, seems odd there's no notification. If that works for your case, great. Another possible option would be to implement `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {}` in your cell, and use that to trigger your layout change (either inside the cell class itself, or via delegate or closure).